# Using XML to maps-transformer in Mule

Tags: mule

I am trying to use the **jdbc-ee:xml-to-maps-transformer`**.

In the flow below, the output at the final logger is empty. I would have expected a Map object which I can use in the insert.

There is some documentation available at

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/JDBC+Transport+Reference#JDBCTransportReference-BasicInsertUpdateDelete

But doesn't help. Any other information on web is quite sparse.

```
 <flow name="inserttinoDBFlow3" doc:name="inserttinoDBFlow3">
    <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" moveToDirectory="src/test/resources/out" path="src/test/resources/in"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payload] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: after object to string:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payload] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: after object to xml :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jdbc-ee:xml-to-maps-transformer doc:name="XML to Maps"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[message.payload]"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Is your XML compliant to the XSD published on the doc page you linked?

Answer (score 1):

> Use a Object-to-XML transformer to transform a Java Object to XML data
>   using XStream.

So you in your flow have Java object of String type in message payload, and tranformer just packed this String in <string> node and encode XML specific characters. And this is not XML that we are wanted in this case.

I removed object-to-xml transformer from your flow and it works.

```
 <flow name="inserttinoDBFlow3" doc:name="inserttinoDBFlow3">
    <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" moveToDirectory="src/test/resources/out" path="src/test/resources/in"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <logger message=" :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: after object to string::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jdbc-ee:xml-to-maps-transformer doc:name="XML to Maps"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[message.payload]"/>
</flow>
```

input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table>
  <record>
    <field name="id" type="java.math.BigDecimal">0</field>
    <field name="name" type="java.lang.String">hello</field>
  </record>
</table>
```

Remember that:

- the xml-to-maps transformer is available with Mule Entreprise Edition only;
- the XML transformed by the xml-to-maps transformer must be compliant to a specific schema